# Convert Varchar type column to BLOB ora-22858

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to convert `VARCHAR` to `BLOB` but I'm getting this error:

> Ora-22858 Invalid alteration of datatype

Comment: what code you used for conversion?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `utl_raw.cast_to_raw()` which convert a varchar2 into a BLOB value, which we used in `Oracle11g`
If you want to convert to CLOB simpy use `TO_CLOB`

Hope this will help.